# Postgresql Run query Alternatively

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 Queries.
They insert rows in account_move which they fetch from a table which has approx 15k rows.
When i execute them, Query 1 first process 15k rows from table at once. Query 2 and Query 3 does the same.
I want them to insert a row one by one. i.e. When executed,
Query 1 - insert one row.
Query 2 - insert one row.
Query 3 - insert one row.
Query 1 - ....
Query 2...... so on.

Query 1:

```
Insert into account_move(create_uid, partner_id, create_date, name, company_id, write_uid, journal_id, state, period_id, write_date, date, ref, to_check)
Select
    1,
    res_partner.id,
    LOCALTIMESTAMP,
    account_invoice.number,
    1,
    1,
    2,
    'posted',
    6,
    LOCALTIMESTAMP,
    date(LOCALTIMESTAMP),
    account_invoice.name,
    FALSE
from account_invoice, sale_order, res_partner, temp_unicom
where account_invoice.origin = sale_order.name and
    sale_order.partner_id = res_partner.id and
    res_partner.ref = temp_unicom.sale_order_item_code;
```

Query 2:

```
Insert into account_move(create_uid, partner_id, create_date, name, company_id, write_uid, journal_id, state, period_id, write_date, date, ref, to_check)
Select
    1,
    res_partner.id,
    LOCALTIMESTAMP,
    '/',
    1,
    1,
    9,
    'draft',
    6,
    LOCALTIMESTAMP,
    date(LOCALTIMESTAMP),
    account_invoice.number,
    FALSE
from account_invoice, sale_order, res_partner, temp_unicom
where account_invoice.origin = sale_order.name and
    sale_order.partner_id = res_partner.id and
    res_partner.ref = temp_unicom.sale_order_item_code;
```

Quecy 3:

```
Insert into account_move(create_uid, partner_id, create_date, name, company_id, write_uid, journal_id, state, period_id, write_date, date, ref, to_check)
Select
    1,
    res_partner.id,
    LOCALTIMESTAMP,
    '/',
    1,
    1,
    9,
    'draft',
    6,
    LOCALTIMESTAMP,
    date(LOCALTIMESTAMP),
    'ST_' || sale_order.name,
    FALSE
from account_invoice, sale_order, res_partner, temp_unicom
where account_invoice.origin = sale_order.name and
    sale_order.partner_id = res_partner.id and
    res_partner.ref = temp_unicom.sale_order_item_code;
```

I also tried nesting but not working.

Comment: Please clarify your question, it is very unclear at the moment. Query 1, 2, 3? A, B, C? Return, from an insert?

Comment: Can you explain **why** the order of insertions is so important for you?

Comment: I am trying to replicate a certain module of which I don't have the code. In that module the data insertion is the same way i am having problem with.

Comment: Ok, but why insertions in 3 consecutive queries is not sufficient? What difference between the two methods are you expecting? (place '@klin' in your answer).

Comment: You seem to be assuming that rows in a table have  a certain order - but they do not. The order of insertion has no relevance to the order in which you retrieve the rows later. Plus "*I want them to insert a row one by one*" - is a bad way of doing things. Processing data "row-by-row" is an anti-pattern with relational databases. Doing things in sets is almost always the better choice.